# Newcommand hangs LaTeX compilation

Tags: latex, renewcommand

I have a problem in the definition of a new command in LaTeX for `lstlisting`. The result is that the compilation hangs without error message, just a `*`.

This hangs the LaTeX compilation:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ssfamily]{exam}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\cs}{\begin{lstlisting}}
\newcommand{\ce}{\end{lstlisting}}
\begin{document}
\cs
program test
  ! This is a commentary
end program test
\ce
\end{document}
```

But this one does not:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ssfamily]{exam}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
program test
  ! This is a commentary
end program test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The only difference is that the beginning and end of endmargin and of `lstlisting` are defined in a new command in the first place. The problem occurs for `lstlisting`, but not for `\begin{center}`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a similar problem, which was reported here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/wrapping-code-listings-verbatim-or-other-method-inside-a-newcommand

It seems that it is not possible to do what I want because the compilation of \begin{lstlisting} needs to search for the corresponding \end{lstlisting} and the newcommands break that.

However, the same result can be obtained defining a new lst environment, using, for instance:

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language=[90]Fortran,
  xleftmargin=1.5cm
}}{}
```

for example. Then, it is possible to define many properties of the code section and the syntax is easier (\begin{code},\end{code}).

The full lstnewenvironment, in my case, is:

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language=[90]Fortran,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{gray},
  xleftmargin=1.5cm,
  morecomment=[l]{!\ }% Comment only with space after !
}}{}
```